# Codeigniter Update Table when Button pressed

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to use Codeigniter to create an application where when a button is pressed that it'll add 1 to an INT column in a table.

There is 3 buttons and depending on which button is pressed it'll update one of the 3 columns adding the value.

I've got so when a user logs in that the username and password they log in with is set into the table with the inputs.

Table:

```
+--+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+
|ID|Password|Username|inputOne|inputTwo|inputThree|
+--+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+
|  |        |        |        |        |          |
|  |        |        |        |        |          |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

After the user is logged in this should be recorded

```
+--+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+
|ID|Password|Username|inputOne|inputTwo|inputThree|
+--+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+
|1 |Pass    |User1   |        |        |          |
|  |        |        |        |        |          |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

I only need it to update the column depending on which button is being pressed. The other columns should not add. Until that button is pressed.

I am also trying to do it so that the page doesn't redirect when the button is pressed.

**The Process:**

**View**

```
    <script src="<?php echo site_url('application/views/js/buttons.js')?>"></script>
    <form method="post">
     <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success" type="submit" id="inputOne" value="Button One"><br><br>
     <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit" id="inputTwo" value="Button Two"><br><br>
     <input class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" type="submit" id="inputThree" value="Button One">
   </form>
```

**buttons.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#inputOne").click(function()
{
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/home/view",
     data: {"1"},
     success:
          function(){
            sleep(5);  //STOP POST
          }
      });
 return false;
});

$("#inputTwo").click(function()
{
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/home/view",
    data: {"1"},
    success:
         function(){
           sleep(5);  //STOP POST
         }
     });
 return false;
});

$("#inputThree").click(function()
{
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/home/view",
   data: {"1"},
   success:
        function(){
          sleep(5);  //STOP POST
        }
    });
 return false;
});


});
```

**Controller**

```
public function buttons() {
 if (!$this->session->userdata('username')){
  redirect (base_URL(). 'index.php/login/view');
 } else {
  if (!$this->session->userdata('password')) {
   redirect (base_URL(). 'index.php/login/view');
  } else {
   if (date('H:i:s') > $this->session->userdata('endTime')) {
     redirect (base_URL(). 'index.php/login/view');
   } else {
     $this->model->load('buttons_model');
   }
  }
 }
}
```

**Model**

```
<?php

class buttons_model extends CI_Model {


      public function __construct()
  {
          parent::__construct();
  }


public function alterinput() {

    $Username = $this->session->userdata('username');
$Password = $this->session->userdata('password');

$sql = "UPDATE input 
 SET inputOne = (inputOne + 1),
  inputTwo = (inputTwo + 1),
  inputThree = (inputThree + 1)
 WHERE (classPassword = '" . $Username . "',
  Username = '" . $Password . "') ";

      $this->db->query($sql);

  //---------------------------------------
  // END OF FILE
  //---------------------------------------
}
```

Where am I going wrong in trying to get the columns to update depending on the button press?

The error I'm getting is that I cannot get the values to enter separately, when Button One is pressed Only inputOne should add and the rest shouldn't

As an example, if I pressed Button One whilst I'm logged in as User1 the table should now look like:

```
+--+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+
|ID|Password|Username|inputOne|inputTwo|inputThree|
+--+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+
|1 |Pass    |User1   |1       |        |          |
|  |        |        |        |        |          |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Please share the code for the update process you have tried and explain what is the error or problem you have

Comment: Added the process from the view, controller and model. Also explained the error I'm getting.

Comment: To what page does the AJAX call? where do you use the alterinput method? why are all three buttons click event the same?

Comment: This is the part where I don't know what I'm doing wrong. The button should call any of the Ajax functions which sends the data to the controller, and after the controller has done it's checks it'll send that data to the buttons_model, which should alter the table with the button pressed.

Also I edited again, with an example on the end to show what I'm trying ot achieve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need one click event for all buttons that runs an AJAX request to a controller that does your process, once the controller finishes and you want to update the DB, call teh model and the method for updating by + 1.

**JS**

```
$(".btn-lg").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // this will prevent the defualt behavior of the button

    // find which button was clicked
    butId = $(this).attr('id');

    $.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: "/controllerDummy/run/",
          data: { button: butId }
        })
      .done(function( msg ) {
        // do something
      });        
});
```

**Controller**

```
// first get the button that was pressed
button = $_POST['button']; // will be the id of the button that was clicked

// do your code here.....

// once completed load the model and run the method of updating...
$this->load->model('button_model');
$this->button_model->methodName();

// if you need it only for specific buttons use an if statement
```

Comment: I have used an if($button == "inputOne") { update one } else if ($button == "inputTwo) { update two } else if($button == "inputThree) { update three} inside of my model but for some reason when I click a button it keeps adding the username and password to another row. The url: "/home/view" is how it's set in my JavaScript.

Comment: From debugging it looks like it's not even running the JavaScript. Is my HTML correct?

Comment: are you passing the variable to the model?

Comment: Yes, but when I'm clicking the button, I added a alert inside of the JavaScript to see if it's running the JavaScript. and I'm not getting any alert back.

Comment: try changing the type of the button to button instead of submit

Comment: I did and it does nothing. It does stop it from adding another row to the table too though. Just some reason when they're being clicked it's not calling the js.

Comment: create a jsfiddle for the html and JS and i will have a look

Comment: change your alert from  `Alert ` to  `alert ` and you will see its working

Comment: I had typed that from my phone. It caused it to auto capitalise. The alert I have in my code is lower case. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76965/discussion-between-lupin-and-lero).